# MS Access Query: Using Select Statement within a Switch function or IIF function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query in which one of two queries is run depending on a specific result. I have `Table A` and `Table B`. `Table B` is sometimes `NULL`, so I wanted the query to say that if `Table B` is null, run this query pulling data from `Table A`, but if `Table B` is NOT null, then run the query pulling data from `Table B`.

I tried a `switch` function as well as an `iif`, but neither worked. Not sure if that's because I messed up the syntax or if neither of these are valid ways of writing this query?

```
SELECT 
SWITCH(
DCOUNT("*",Table_B) = 0, 
(SELECT *
INTO Result_Table
FROM Table_A),
DCOUNT(*,Table_B) <> 0,
(SELECT *
INTO Result_Table
FROM Table_B)
```

```
SELECT
IIF(DCOUNT(*,Table_B) = 0,
(SELECT *
FROM Table_A),
(SELECT *
FROM A))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they have the same columns, you seem to want `union all` with `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b);
```

If the columns are not the same, then select the columns that you want -- perhaps using `NULL` for missing columns from one of the tables.

Comment: Thank you! I saw a few people mention unions for similar things, but was thinking of them in the traditional term of just joining two tables together which I didn't want if my Table B wasn't null. Is the where not exists statement here saying if it isn't in Table A, then get it from Table B?

Comment: @beatrixb . . . You understand the query correctly.